# How can I estimate the travel time of a route by using a travel time matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I want to compute the travel time of a route by using a travel time matrix I already have. Specifically, I have a list of lists that indicates the routes' nodes.

```
routes= [[1, 2, 3, -1, -1],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, -1]]
```

The `-1` indicates that the route ends. So, in this example I have 2 routes:

```
Route 1: 1>2>3
Route 2: 1>2>3>4
```

Also, I have the following travel time matrix (list of lists):

```
tt= [[0, 4, 5, 1], 
    [5, 0, 9, 2],
    [1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

So what I want to achieve is to estimate the travel time of the routes. The result is the following:

`Route 1= 4(1>2) + 9(2>3) + 0(because it's from 3 to -1)` (=13)
`Route 2= 4(1>2) + 9(2>3) + 1(3>4) + 0(because it's from 4 to -1)` (=14)

Results can be stored in a list. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you just want the sum of each sublist until a negative appears?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the indeces from the routes matrix and take the appropriate elements from the travel time (tt) matrix as I described in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting the numbers you've used in your example of time travelled from? (Route1: 4 + 9 + 0 (=13) Route2: 4 + 9 + 1 + 0 (=14))

Comment: So let me elaborate: Route 1= 4(1>2) + 9(2>3) + 0(because it's from 3 to -1), Route 2= 4(1>2) + 9(2>3) + 1(3>4) + 0(because it's from 4 to -1)

Comment: Do you ever use the other lists of tt? or just the first?

Comment: tt is the matrix (list of lists) that mentions the time needed to travel among the nodes. For example the element [1,2] (in the table its the number 4) says that from node 1 to node 2 we need 4 time units to travel. That's the logic behind this table

Comment: So when would you use the second row/list onwards in tt? Your example for the 2 routes both use the first row/list

Comment: each row from the matrix corresponds to the origin and column is the destination

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

routes= [[1, 2, 3, -1, -1], [1, 2,  3, 4, -1]]

tt = [[0, 4, 5, 1], 
    [5, 0, 9, 2],
    [1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0]]

tt_sum = []

for route in routes:

    counter = 0
    tt_route = 0
    
    for i in range(4):
        if route[i+1] != -1:
            tt_route += tt[counter][route[i]]
            counter += 1

    tt_sum.append(tt_route)
```

This gives `tt_sum` as `[13, 14]`.